Why can't I call the custom dialog elements?
I'm trying to control the text and the button on my custom dialog.
but for some reason when calling the text and the button, the dialog doesn't show.
I need to delete the text and button part for the dialog to show. Why is that happening?
 private void showMessage()
    {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Test2.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.finish_question);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            TextView finalScore =  dialog.findViewById(R.id.finalScore);
            AppCompatButton close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
            finalScore.setText(score);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

    }

you can see that I have called the elements the right way, by using dialog.findViewById, so why isn't working?
Here is my layout :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="النتيجة:"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalScore"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView

        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/5"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:text="إنهاء"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout> 

is there another way to call the elements of a dialog?
